# perl.exe runs from any folder, and perldoc.bat is not. Meanwhile they both are located in the same folder

Tags: eclipse, perl, activestate, epic, perldoc

I use ActiveState Perl 5.8.8 with Eclipse/EPIC. And it works fine. I'd like to use perldoc as well. But there is message in Eclipse "Documentation is not available." in Eclipse my perl interpreter is "C:\perl\bin\perlexe". Or if I type in cmd "perldoc" appears a message "Can't find perldoc on PATH." Sure, in system env variables C:\perl\bin path exists. perl.exe and perldoc.bat are located in the same folder, but perl works and perldoc is not. But is I go before to perl folder in cmd "cd C:\perl\bin" and type perldoc, then perldoc works well. I checked my environment variables again, but I couldn't detect any problem there - "C:\perl\bin" is in very beginning of variables in PATH, perl.exe and perldoc.bat are both located in this folder.

Comment: Type `where perl` and `where perldoc` and see what happens. Is the output of the first the same directory where perldoc exists (or, is it where you expect it to be)?

Comment: C:\>where perl 
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). 

C:\>where perldoc 
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). 

C:\>perl -v 

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread 
(with 18 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: Are you running in some kind of pseudo-unix shell, such as Cygwin, or one provided by ActiveState?

Comment: No, I'm running on cmd for now. (OS Windows 7)

Comment: It's possible that Eclipse is ignoring PATHEXT, the environment variable that tells "DOS" (don't flame me for that incorrect term!) which extensions to add on to the given program name, if the exact program name is not found.  For example, if you type `perl` in DOS, it will look for "perl", "perl.exe", "perl.bat", etc, in each dir in the PATH, until it finds a match.  If Eclipse is not using PATHEXT, then try configuring it to use (or typing) `perldoc.bat` instead of just `perldoc`.

Comment: perl interpreter works fine in Eclipse. But there no way to define perldoc path inside of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "perldoc.bat" that couldn't be found. There should be a Perl script named "perldoc" (with no file extension) in the same directory as "perldoc.bat". The message "Can't find %s on PATH" comes from Perl itself and means (see [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)):

> You used the -S switch, but the script to execute could not be found
>   in the PATH.

(It's "perldoc.bat" that runs Perl with the "-S" switch, in order to launch the "perldoc" script.)

I don't know why you were missing the "perldoc" script.